# Авторизация JSP

Tags: jsp, html, java, авторизация

Всем привет.

У меня такая проблема: есть два поля для авторизации, есть кнопка. Как в `JSP` считать значения этих полей в какую нибудь переменную (чтобы записать в сессию).

Через `request.getParameter` не хотелось бы, потому что тогда логин и пароль отображаются в строке. Если есть какой то стандартный вариант, то предложите, пожалуйста.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Есть такой тип запроса на сервер как POST. Используйте его. На сервер никак, кроме как запросом, не отправить данные.

Comment: post запрос, в сервлете или еще где - берете данные из request и записываете в session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```

В чем проблемы то?

---

Ответ на коммент

А почему у тебя сначала поле ввода, а потом форма?

Что бы не было пароля в строке браузера, используй POST

Как-то так:

```
<form action="" method="POST"> 
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Log In">
 </form>
<%
if(request.getParameter("password") == null){
    if(request.getParameter("password").equals("")) {
            out.println("<html><font color=red>Введи пароль мудила</font></html>");
    } else {
        String password= request.getParameter( "password" );
            session.setAttribute( "password", password );   
    }
}
%>
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я не хочу включать поле password в тег "Form"  
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<form action= "Page2.jsp" method="get">
 <input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
чтобы на следующей странице пароль не отображался в строке адреса.

В общем мне нужно либо на этой же странице как то выдрать пароль и засунуть его в сессию, либо на следующей странице, но так, чтобы пароль нигде видно не было.

Comment: ООО! Красота красивая. Все работает. Спасибо тебе добрый человек!

Answer (score 0):

А не легче просто в форму где пароль TYPE поставить PASSWORD, тогда при вводе будут звездочки, а не вводимые символы? Или я что то не так понял?

Comment: Это понятно, что можно поставить тип поля password, я не знаю как потом вытащить значение из этого поля в переменную типа String.

Comment: @deeplulz браузеры подставляют в это поле пароли если юзер выбрал запомнить... что не всегда желательно.

Answer (score 0):

Здарвствуйте!

Первое!
НИКОГДА НЕ ПИШИТЕ ЛОГИКУ В JSP!!!!11 Для этого сущевствуют по крайней мере сервлеты, ан который может быть отправлен запрос, а еще лучше `Spring MVC + Spring Security` который и поможет решить проблему авторизации.

Писать логику в `JSP` - почти преступно.

Второе.

```
public class ServletDemo extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException{
        // здесь можно поучить любую инфу, вызвать нужные сервсисы и т.д.
    }
}
```

А по поводу авторизации можно посмотреть тут - [The Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html)